# How frequently should I be calling sql.Open in my program?

Tags: go

As the title says I don't know if having multiple `sql.Open` statements is a good or bad thing or what or if I should have a file with just an init that is something like:

```
var db *sql.DB


func init() {
    var err error
    db, err = sql.Open
}
```

just wondering what the best practice would be. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should at least check the error.
As mentioned in "[Connecting to a database](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SQLInterface#connecting-to-a-database)":

> Note that `Open` does not directly open a database connection: this is deferred until a query is made. To verify that a connection can be made before making a query, use the `Ping` function:

```
if err := db.Ping(); err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
```

> After use, the database is closed using Close.

If possible, limit the number of opened connection to a database to a minimum.
See "[Go/Golang sql.DB reuse in functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19986504/6309)":

> You shouldn't need to open database connections all over the place.
>   The `database/sql` package does connection pooling internally, opening and closing connections as needed, while providing the illusion of a single connection that can be used concurrently.

As [elithrar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/556573/elithrar) points out [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578876/how-frequently-should-i-be-calling-sql-open-in-my-program/33578897#comment54935511_33578897), [`database.sql/#Open`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Open) does mention:

> The returned DB is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines and maintains its own pool of idle connections.
>   **Thus, the `Open` function should be called just once.**
>   It is rarely necessary to close a DB.

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19978147/6309)

> Declaring `*sql.DB` globally also have some additional benefits such as [`SetMaxIdleConns`](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.SetMaxIdleConns) (regulating connection pool size) or [preparing](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Prepare) SQL statements across your application.

You can use a [function `init`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24790175/6309), which will run even if you don't have a `main()`:

```
var db *sql.DB
func init() {
    db, err = sql.Open(DBparms....)
}
```

> `init()` is always called, regardless if there's main or not, so if you import a package that has an init function, it will be executed.
>   You can have multiple `init()` functions per package, they will be executed in the order they show up in the code (after all variables are initialized of course).

Comment: Would you say the way I have described in my original post is a decent way to do it? Set a db global variable for my package and set it with an `init` then `ping` it? Where would I put the `defer close`? Your answer is fantastic and answers most questions, just the one other thing was what's the best way to open the initial connection. Like if I don't have a `main()` function. Thanks!

Comment: @Datsik - one global pool (either as a global var, or with a pointer you pass around explicitly) is fine - see https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Open - `Thus, the Open function should be called just once.`

Comment: Hey thanks for the fantastic answer. Would it be bad practice to have a file with just an init because as it stands I have 2 files in my package with no main because I don't need one can I add a third one and call it `init.go` just to declare my db?

Comment: @Datsik no, that would not be a bad practice.